# How to update plist's address to Mapview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I follow below code, the output can printed to the console, but how to update on the MapView?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    /* We have our address */
    NSString *oreillyAddress = @"1005 Gravenstein Highway North, Sebastopol, CA 95472, USA";

    /* We will later insert the address and the format that we want our output in, into this API's URL */
    NSString *geocodingURL = @"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=%@";
    /* Insert the address and the output format into the URL */
    NSString *finalURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:geocodingURL, oreillyAddress, GOOGLE_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CSV];
    /* Now escape the URL using appropriate percentage marks */

    finalURL = [finalURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    /* Create our URL */
    NSURL *urlToCall = [NSURL URLWithString:finalURL];
    /* And a request for the connection using the URL */
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToCall];

    /* We will put all the connection's received data into this instance of the NSMutableData class */
    NSMutableData *newMutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.connectionData = newMutableData;
    [newMutableData release];
    NSURLConnection *newConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    /* Create the connection and start the downloading of geocoding results */
    self.myConnection = newConnection;
    [newConnection release];
}

- (void) viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self.myConnection cancel];
    self.myConnection = nil;
    self.connectionData = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    /* Support all orientations */
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myConnection cancel];
    [myConnection release];
    [connectionData release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting the lat-long information for the location. You will have to create a class that adopts the [`MKAnnotation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and add an instance of it storing the location you get to the `MKMapView` object using the `addAnnotation:` method. If the location is within the displayed region of the map, the map view object will call the delegate method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` to get the view to display for that annotation. So you will have to become the delegate by adopting the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. Implement the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method to return an `MKPinAnnotationView` instance or your own subclass' of `MKAnnotationView`.

If the location is not within the displayed region, then use `setRegion:animated:` method to move to the location.

Comment: @Gere Tan Did this help? Do you need any further assistance on this?